# Modern words for "contrariwise"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, adverbs

Does *contrariwise* sound old-fashioned?  As in *Alice in Wonderland*:

> ‘**Contrariwise**,’ continued Tweedledee, ‘if it was so, it might be.’

What are the modern words for *contrariwise*?

Comment: It's a phrase: *on the contrary*.

Comment: Also, "to the contrary". It would help if you gave us a complete sentence. It's possible that context would make a difference.

Comment: @chasly from UK: I don't know if [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+contrary+I%2Cto+the+contrary+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20contrary%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20contrary%20I%3B%2Cc0) offers *proof **to** the contrary* (or indeed, *in support* of my contention here), but I think there are only a limited number of contexts where ***to*** is more natural than ***on***.

Comment: @Anonym That was my thought, too. But on reflection, that's not what *contrariwise* means: it signifies an inversion of terms. 'I know what you're thinking about,' said Tweedledum; 'but it isn't so, nohow.'
'Contrariwise,' continued Tweedledee, 'if it was so, it might be; and if it were so, it would be; but as it isn't, it ain't. That's logic.' *From the opposite perspective* is a little closer, but still not right. We need John Lawler here.

Comment: @If you add  'contrariwise I' to your graph you see that it has rarely been as popular as either of the other two. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+contrary+I%2Cto+the+contrary+I%2Ccontrariwise+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20contrary%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20contrary%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontrariwise%20I%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Contrariwise*** is not Just old-fashioned, It was (very likely) invented to fit Tweedledum and Tweedledee who have been fished out of a nursery rhyme where they fight over a rattle, and are odd little kids. But take your choice:

[**vice versa**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vice-versa)

"Tweedledum said Tweedledee had started the fight and *vice versa."*
"Tweedledum said Tweedledee had started the fight; contrariwise Tweedledee said it was Tweedledum."

[**the opposite**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/opposite)

"Tweedledum said the tar-barrel was a crow; contrariwise Tweedledee said the  crow was a monstrous tar-barrel."
"Tweedledum said the crow was tar-barrel, but Tweedledee said the very opposite."

**on the contrary**

Tweedledum said Tweedledee had forgotten what the quarrel was about; contrariwise Tweedledee forgot where he put his helmet.
This is where I would use *on the contrary*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think it does sound old-fashioned, however this is purely subjective. That from my experience the word isn't used often in conversation indicates this. An alternative and more popular phrase would be *on the contrary*.

Comment: I suspect this is as close as we're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

*Contrariwise* draws attention to itself and so runs a risk of distracting the reader or listener from your message.

In most contexts when you might want to use contrariwise I'd probably say *on the other hand*.